# Invert 24 bit color

Tags: c, colors, bit-shift

Given an struct array of pixels in an image struct, I want to switch the red and blue values for the entire image. I'm not quite sure how to bit shift them. They are stored in a struct such that the value is red then green then blue. Each color is 8 bits, so size is 24. So far this is what I have.

```
    for (int row = 0; i < image->height;row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < image->width; column++) {
        image->pixels[column + row * image->width] = image->pixels[column + row * image->width].red & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        image->pixels[column + row * image->width] = (image->pixels[column + row * image->width].blue>>16) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this code do? Does it compile? What is the type of `pixels`?

Comment: Why are you addresing [i + j * i]? I suspect that you should multiply j by image->width...

Comment: @Blake Lassiter: Er... what is `.red` and `.blue`? Your description states that RBG data is stored in 24-bit packed form, while your code assumes that it is stored in different fields (`.red` and `.blue`). So, what is it?

Comment: `i + j * i` is not the correct index. The correct index is `row * width + column`, and the outer loop should be counting rows, i.e. the outer loop should be `for (row=0;row<height;row++)`. And you need to add the declaration of the `image` structure to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `pixels` is an array of long and `i + j * i` is indeed the right address, this should do the trick. Use `&` to isolate the bytes and shifting to combine the parts into a new long.

The problem in your own code, is that you assign the intermediate result back to the pixel. By doing so, you change it, thereby influencing the second step. You could do in in multiple steps if you assign the intermediate results to a separate variable. But I'd prefer to do it in one assignment:

```
long pixel = i + j * image->width; // Pixel index

image->pixels[pixel] = 
   (image->pixels[pixel] & 0xFF) << 16 + // Red, shift to position of blue
   (image->pixels[pixel] & 0xFF00) + // Green, stay in place
   (image->pixels[pixel] & 0xFF0000) >> 16; // Blue, shift right to position of red.
```

Comment: Downvoter, can you please explain what is wrong, so I can either improve or delete my answer?

Comment: Sorry, should have commented first. I've added a comment to the question which explains why the indexing is wrong. And without the structure definition, you're only guessing at the definition of `pixels`.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the feedback. Good point about the index. I didn't pay much attention to that part at first. The pixels themselves was an educated guess, based on the way OP tried to bitshift and assign to them.

Comment: @GolezTrol thank you, that makes sense and the comments help. I do need to fix the indexing because it isn't quite right

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown what type the elements of your `image` array are, but if it's a structure with `.red` and `.blue` (and presumably `.green`) fields, you shouldn't need any bit-shifting at all; you can just swap the values in those fields.

```
uint8_t temp = image->pixels[i + j * i].red;
image->pixels[i + j * i].red = image->pixels[i + j * i].blue;
image->pixels[i + j * i].blue = temp;
```

Comment: I wanted to do it with bit shift, but I could do it as you wrote.